# What's this weird gap in some corners in my svg text?

Tags: css, animation, svg, css-animations, svg-animate

I'm testing svg animation with this outlined text that I created in Illustrator.
Here is the animation I'm working on.

https://jsfiddle.net/kaguraichi123/4rkucmL7/3/

First, I noticed this gap in some corners like the one in the image below.

[image]

So I put this CSS.

```
svg{
    stroke-linecap: square;
}
```

I managed to fill the gaps somehow, but the only letter that's been fixed is B, I'm assuming it's because the corder was 90 degrees.
The other letters A, R and N, now have broken corners, as you can see in the image down below.

[image]

My question is, what's causing this gap in the first place? Also, is there any way to fix these gaps? I want the letter such as A to have sharp and crisp corners.

Thank you very much.

**(Edit1)**
This image shows where this gap is located originally. Please note that the letter "B" looks fine in jsfiddle because of the CSS property "stroke-linecap: square".

[image]

**(Edit2)**
With the following CSS property,

```
svg{
    stroke-linecap: round;
}
```

you get the result down below. As you can see, the corresponding corners are round now, and I want them to have sharp corners like the others.

[image]

Comment: Looks fine to me. What are you using to display the SVG?

Comment: There is also stroke-linejoin property. Try to use it

Comment: @RobertLongson What I did was make the text in Illustrator and export it as svg and copy and paste the code in HTML.

Comment: @YuriiKovalenko Thank you for your input. I put the property in the second path(letter "A") in HTML, you can check it in the jsfiddle link in the post. Unfortunately, it didn't solve the issue.

Comment: I've updated my post to show exactly where there's this problem. Please take a look at the image at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

The `square` linecap will fuse line ends only for lines that meet in a right angle, which in your example only the letter `B` is composed of.

Try

```
svg{
    stroke-linecap: round;
}
```

for smoother results.

Comment: Thank you very much. Yes, I've tried this property as well, and I find it smooth from the distance. However, if you take a closer look at the corners, you find them round because of the property, which is not what I'm aiming for. I've updated my post with a new image to show what I meant. (Edit2) Thank you again.